# AS 3 : Existing Function doesn't found?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

There a strange bug on my program compilation...

For my program scenario, it's just a MovieClip names "perso" who move with keyboard's arrows.

Flash says me that "clavierUp" and "animation" property access can't be find.

I really don't understand...

```
var perso:Perso = new Perso();

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, clavierDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, clavierUp);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animation);

function clavierDown(e)
{
    switch(e.keyCode)
    {   
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
            perso.speedX = -speedHero;
            break;
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
            perso.speedX = speedHero;
            break;
        case Keyboard.UP:
            perso.speedY = -speedHero;
            break;
        case Keyboard.DOWN:
            perso.speedY = speedHero;
            break;
    }

function clavierUp(e)
{
    switch(e.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
            perso.speedX = 0;
            perso.scaleX = -1;
            break;  

        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
            perso.speedX = 0;
            perso.scaleX = 1;
            break;

        case Keyboard.UP:
            perso.speedY = 0;
            break;

            case Keyboard.DOWN:
            perso.speedY = 0;
            break;
    }
}

function animation(e)
{
    animeHero();
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: post your source file.  are you using flash professional and coding on the timeline?  or .as class files?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i just missed a rightbrace at the end of "clavierDown" function...